# JQ command to extract names into an array from a String

Tags: arrays, json, string, jq

Input is a document . I will get names in a String preceded by number

```
 {"doc": [
    {
      "cNo": "6222332 22450 32",
      "cNames": " 1 MANJSY JOAU 2 CHAFANH BINO",
      "cExpiry": "04/2025"
    },
    {
      "fields": 3,
      "documents": 1
    }
  ]}
```

The expected output is a name array sometime like shown below

```
 {"doc": [
    {
      "cNo": "6222332 22450 32",
      "cNameArray": [
                       "MANJSY JOAU",
                       "CHAFANH BINO"
                    ],
      "cExpiry": "04/2025"
    },
    {
      "fields": 3,
      "documents": 1
    }
  ]}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  To avoid having your questions downvoted, please follow the [mcve] guidelines: (1) Giving a single example without a description of the general requirements is usually insufficient. (2) It is usually a good idea to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The question as I understand it has two main parts:

1. Converting a string with integer and non-integer segments to an array
2. Changing the key name from cNames to cNameArray

In the present context, the first part could be accomplished by:

```
.doc[0] |= (.cNames |= [splits(" *[0-9] *")][1:])
```

And the second could be accomplished by using `with_entries`, thus preserving the ordering of the keys:

```
.doc[0] |= (.cNames |= [splits(" *[0-9] *")][1:]
            | with_entries(if .key == "cNames" 
                           then .key = "cNameArray"
                           else . end) )
```

Comment: I tried with {name: [split("[0-9] *")][1:]}

but i get this error
jq: error (at <stdin>:2): split input and separator must be strings
exit status 5

Comment: the requirement is basically to extract the names of people .. from a String thats like 
1 charles john 2 mary kani 3 bijuhn mag

Comment: I thought it was obvious that you have to extract `.names`.  See update.

Comment: Can you help me with the name extraction, if my input is something like this


"obj" : [{
   "title": "Some Title",
   "tags":"1 tagA 2 tag-B 3 tagC"
 },
 {
      "numberOfFields": 3,
      "numberOfFieldsExtracted": 3,
      "numberOfDocuments": 1
 }]

Comment: That is not valid JSON.  I would suggest you update your Q by adding another example input and corresponding desired output.